# bind mounting read-only using fstab?

Tags: linux, mount

I'm using `mount --bind` to attach a certain directory under another path (it is part of a system that holds multiple copies of mirrors where some copies are slightly different then others but I don't want some parts to be duplicated, such as ISOs).

The problem is that I would really like the bind mounts to be read-only, but when I write in `/etc/fstab` that these mounts have the options `ro,bind` and issue `mount -a`, I get this:

```
mount: warning: /some/target/path seems to be mounted read-write.
```

And indeed it is - it looks like the `ro` option is being ignored and the warning is probably because mount rechecks the mount after its done.

According to the mount man page:

> Note  that the filesystem mount options will remain the same as those on the original mount point, and cannot be changed by passing the -o option along with --bind/--rbind. The mount options  can  be  changed  by  a  separate remount command

And the solution given is to issue the `mount` command followed by `mount -o remount,ro` - which doesn't work well when using `/etc/fstab` for mounting. Any ideas how to work around that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer which works for me on debian.  It's from:

http://www.sagui.org/~gustavo/blog/fedora/read-only-bind-mount.html

```
/source/dir            /destination/dir    none  bind            0 0
/source/dir            /destination/dir    none  remount,bind,ro 0 0
```

If that doesn't work, you could do put the mount commands in rc.local.  Which is ugly.

Comment: the mount manual recommends this solution under the bind section (`man mount`)

Comment: This no longer works with systemd since systemd does not allow duplicate entries in fstab since it does not follow fstab sequentially because it mounts in parallel. Since util-linux >= 2.27 an explicit remount is not needed to make the bind readonly, but I believe is still needed for some other options like noexec. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128336/61655

Answer (score 0):

I would say it'd be easiest to get over your desire to have the mounts read-only.  Based on the information provided I see no reason why they need to be so.

Comment: Granted, but I'm stubborn that way ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, all that gets you is an ulcer and a hatred of your job; it doesn't get you read-only bind mounts.

Answer (score 0):

```
/source/dir  /destination/dir  none  bind            0 0
/source/dir  /destination/dir  none  remount,bind,ro 0 0
```

by i test this is not use on ubuntu 14.04 X 64 OS